# Chrome: advanced usage of dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I faced few problems while using Chrome dev tool. Just want to know whether it's possible and if yes - how. Suggest I have a really massive client side, with hundred of responses per page.

1. *How to find endpoint which handle the response?* I mean the first place in js code where the response come in.
2. *How to find the response by it content?* For instance, I want to know in which response I've got `45902309509902` value from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to find endpoint which handle the response?

On the Network tab, you can see where the request was *originated*, it's the column labelled "Initiator:"

[image]

That has a link that will show you the code originating the ajax call (I assume by "response" you're talking about an ajax response). From there, you should be able to find the callback that request is associated with. A lot of times, if you use a library like jQuery, you'll be shown the jQuery code doing the request rather than yours. You can still find what you need, though, by using the un-minified version of the libray, setting a breakpoint on that code (perhaps even a conditional one on, say, the URL being requested), and then when the breakpoint is hit using the call stack to find out where in your code the call actually originates.

> How to find the response by it content?

This will be slightly more difficult. Again in the Network tab, you can click each ajax request and see (and search through) the text of there response under the Response sub-tab.